# Java - DAO+Hibernate+JPA+JDBC+Tomcat+Servlet

Tags: java, design-pattern

Estou avançando o curso de Java e deparei com DAO, JPA, Servlet, Hibernate e Tomcat.
Entendo que o DAO lida com o banco de dados, que o Hibernate é um framework pra isso, que o JPA transcreve de orientado a objeto para entidades. Ainda, que o Tomcat e Servlet fornecem programa no lado servidor do tipo HTML para funcionar protocolo HTTP. 
Entretanto, estou com uma aplicação que usa tudo e estou confuso como todas operam em conjunto! Alguém pode me ajudar a encaixar todos? Não preciso de código, mas uma explicação teórica do significado de como operam em conjunto. Obrigado pela ajuda. Tem alguma referência de livro ou site que possa me esclarecer em detalhes?

Answer (score 2):

No DAO você pode separar sua lógica de acesso ao banco da sua lógica dos controllers, por exemplo.

No caso de um sistema de cadastro de produtos teríamos as classes: Produto, ProdutoDAO, SessionFactory/EntityFactory.

No ProdutoDAO é onde teremos a lógica de acesso a banco, a conexão do banco pode ser feita a partir de JPA ou de Hibernate mesmo, falando de uma forma bem simples, o JPA faz a conexão pra ti, utilizando por baixo dos panos o hibernate.
Então no seu DAO você terá uma chamada de uma factory de conexão com o banco, pode ser uma SessionFactory no caso de Hibernate ou uma EntityFactory no caso do JPA.

O JDBC é bascicamente a conexão do java com o banco de dados, antigamente, antes tecnologias como a do Hibernate e do JPA precisávamos ter uma classe JDBC onde faríamos toda nossa lógica de conexão e chamadas de banco (selects, inserts, updates, deletes), utilizando essas tecnologias, já ganhamos essas lógicas semi prontas, bastando apenas chamá-las, como por exemplo o persist(dado) do JPA, que fará um insert no banco pra ti.

As classes servlets te permitem a criação de páginas web dinâmicas. 
O nome servlet vem da ideia de um pequeno servidor cujo objetivo é receber chamadas HTTP, processá-las e devolver uma resposta ao cliente. Cada servlet é, portanto, um objeto Java que recebe tais requisições (request) e produz algo (response), como uma página HTML dinamicamente gerada.
E o Tomcat é um software que você utiliza para subir seu servidor e fazer deploy do seu projeto nele, ele é um contêiner de servlets.

Você pode seguir os cursos gratuitos da Caelum, sobre desenvolvimento Java web: 
[Caelum Desenvolvimento web java](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/#null)

Se quiser se aprofundar mais, você pode fazer esse sobre Desenvolvimento web com vraptor:
[Caelum Desenvolvimento web ágil com vraptor](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-vraptor-hibernate/novo-projeto/)

Apenas lembrando que minha explicação foi beeemmm superficial! Mas espero ter ajudado =D

Comment: Poxa, muito obrigado!